# why do i see this error :Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined while running my page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote a code to read JSON Object into Bootstrap table. Initially the code was working. Later i have moved the entire folder to desktop. When i tried again i started getting the error. I am not sure what is wrong.

```
  var data = [{
       "eventInfo": {
        "context": {
          "siteTimezone": "Asia/Brunei",
          "entityPk": "8802089762861",
          "entityClass": "de.hybris.platform.core.model.order.OrderModel",
          "com.amway.core.events.model.AmwayEventQueueEntryModel": "8805563195834"
        },
        "isoCountryCode": "BN",
        "eventType": "ORDER_CONFIRMED",
        "entityType": "salesorder",
        "sourceTimestamp": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.683+08:00",
        "sourceApplication": "HYBRIS",
        "affiliateCode": "100",
        "entityId": "7100029639",
        "sourceEventId": "4521231e-c347-459b-8d46-43cd2010c8c1",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "sourceHost": "ip-10-127-165-135.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal"
      },
      "entity": {
        "lynxIsPCP": false,
        "paymentRequired": true,
        "bonusTransactionRequired": true,
        "addresses": [{
            "telephoneNumber": "03-7946 2800",
            "isoCountryCode": "BN",
            "line3": "Bandar Seri Begawan",
            "cityName": "Brunei",
            "line2": "Kampung Kiulap",
            "line1": "6 & 7, Block A, Kompleks Shakirin",
            "careOfName": "",
            "state": "BR",
            "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
            "postalCode": "BE1518",
            "id": "8804188225559"
          },
          {
            "telephoneNumber": "5494492",
            "isoCountryCode": "BN",
            "line3": "GADONG",
            "line4": "8171571",
            "cityName": "BDR SERI BEGAWAN",
            "line2": "KAMPONG RIMBA",
            "line1": "5 SIMPANG 12-32",
            "careOfName": "",
            "state": "BR",
            "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
            "postalCode": "BE3119",
            "id": "8802223521815"
          },
          {
            "telephoneNumber": "5494492",
            "isoCountryCode": "BN",
            "line3": "GADONG",
            "line4": "8171571",
            "cityName": "BDR SERI BEGAWAN",
            "line2": "KAMPONG RIMBA",
            "line1": "5 SIMPANG 12-32",
            "careOfName": "",
            "state": "BR",
            "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
            "postalCode": "BE3119",
            "id": "8802223521815"
          },
          {
            "telephoneNumber": "03-7946 2800",
            "isoCountryCode": "BN",
            "line3": "Bandar Seri Begawan",
            "cityName": "Brunei",
            "line2": "Kampung Kiulap",
            "line1": "6 & 7, Block A, Kompleks Shakirin",
            "careOfName": "",
            "state": "BR",
            "emailAddress": "myhelpdesk@Amway.com",
            "postalCode": "BE1518",
            "id": "8800157073431"
          }
        ],
        "totalOrderValue": 147.5,
        "lynxPaymentChangePaid": 0.0,
        "lynxIsRepair": false,
        "adjustments": [],
        "requestedDeliveryServiceLevel": "walkin",
        "lynxTenure": 0,
        "saleCountryCode": "BN",
        "orderDateTime": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.328+08:00",
        "invoiceSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "userAgent": "Suresh Mathiarasu",
        "orderStatus": "CONFIRMED",
        "isoCurrencyCode": "BND",
        "fees": [{
          "feeCode": "walkin",
          "feeTaxTotalAmount": 0.0,
          "lynxRefunded": false,
          "feeAmount": 0.0,
          "feeTaxDetails": [{
            "taxAmount": 0.0,
            "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
          }]
        }],
        "bonusPeriod": "202006",
        "orderingPartyId": "40986385",
        "lynxPayerPartyId": "40986385",
        "salesChannelCode": "Point of Sale",
        "lynxIsEpp": false,
        "lynxPayerPartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
        "lynxDemandLocationName": "BN",
        "lynxDeliveryType": "pis",
        "paymentSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "orderPriceList": "AmwayDefaultABOPriceGroup",
        "lynxVolumePartyId": "40986385",
        "lynxHasSopEntries": false,
        "orderLines": [{
          "linePrice": 147.5,
          "itemType": "AmwayVariantProduct",
          "itemBV": 29.5,
          "lynxBirTaxPerUnit": 0.0,
          "lynxInvoiceNumber": "130099000",
          "lynxLineAdjustedPV": 0.0,
          "shippedQuantity": 0,
          "lineStatus": "OPEN",
          "lynxProductSerialNumber": [],
          "lineUnitOfMeasure": "EA",
          "allocatedQuantity": 5,
          "linePVAmount": 95.0,
          "lynxBmCode": [],
          "lastUpdateDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.469+08:00",
          "lynxBillingAddressReference": "8802223521815",
          "cancelledQuantity": 0,
          "lynxBaseItemId": "115383D",
          "demandLocation": "T45",
          "backorderedQuantity": 0,
          "taxNotRequired": false,
          "pickupAddressReference": "8804188225559",
          "unallocatedQuantity": 0,
          "pendingQuantity": 5,
          "itemABOPrice": 29.5,
          "lineTaxTotalAmount": 0.0,
          "lynxIsSopLine": false,
          "lynxWasBackorder": false,
          "itemSuggestedRetailPrice": 37.0,
          "lineTotalValue": 147.5,
          "baseItemId": "115383D",
          "lynxMasterCode": [],
          "itemDescription": "ARTISTRY SIGNATURE COLOR Lipstick - Daring Red (06) (3.8g)",
          "lineTaxDetails": [{
            "taxAmount": 0.0,
            "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
          }],
          "shipAddressReference": "8804188225559",
          "lynxPickupAddressName": "BN",
          "lynxIsSopEntry": false,
          "lynxBirAcknowledgementResetCounter": "1",
          "lynxLineAdjustedBV": 0.0,
          "orderedQuantity": 5,
          "itemListPrice": 29.5,
          "fulfillmentType": "walkin",
          "returnedQuantity": 0,
          "orderLineId": 0,
          "itemPV": 19.0,
          "lineBVAmount": 147.5
        }],
        "lynxFulfillmentAddressReference": "8800157073431",
        "cashierBatchId": "amwaybrunei-AM-BN-BN-T45-MY020394-1593058911313",
        "lynxOrderingPartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
        "totalBVAmount": 147.5,
        "lynxVolumeTransactions": [],
        "volumeSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "taxDetails": [{
          "taxAmount": 0.0,
          "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
        }],
        "lynxUserType": "AmwayBusinessNature_1",
        "lynxPaymentTenderedAmount": 147.5,
        "lynxVolumePartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
        "lynxOrderCreatedBy": "MY020394",
        "lynxOms": "Hybris",
        "orderForSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "lynxPaymentInstalmentType": "PIF",
        "lynxMemberPoints": 0.0,
        "lynxContactPhone": "5494492",
        "totalPVAmount": 95.0,
        "inventoryTransactionRequired": true,
        "lynxIsEventBooking": false,
        "lynxBirCashierId": "MY020394",
        "refunds": [],
        "invoiceWithConsignmentRequired": false,
        "orderPeriod": "202006",
        "orderingSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "lynxContactEmailId": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
        "amwaySalesEntity": "780",
        "paymentStatus": "PAID",
        "storefront": "amwaybrunei",
        "lynxPaymentType": "PIF",
        "salesOrderId": "7100029639",
        "lynxOrderCategory": "selfOrder",
        "payments": [{
          "verificationDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:54.453+08:00",
          "lynxIsConnectedFlow": false,
          "paymentLocation": "T45",
          "lynxPaymentProcessedBy": "8055817",
          "paymentStatus": "ACCEPTED",
          "terminalId": "MY020394",
          "paymentReferenceId": "TXN-1593065154321",
          "payerSalesAccount": {
            "accountId": "8055817",
            "lynxPinLevel": "330",
            "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
            "affiliateCode": "100"
          },
          "paymentDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:54.456+08:00",
          "isoCurrencyCode": "BND",
          "lynxPaymentInformation": "",
          "paymentId": "831122002_4e7c1945-b49d-4c86-a0b8-a05b0cb805fa",
          "paymentValue": 147.5,
          "paymentMethod": "cash",
          "merchantId": "amway"
        }],
        "shipToSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "totalABORetailProfit": 0.0,
        "totalTaxAmount": 0.0,
        "lynxOrderType": "NORMAL_ORDER",
        "lynxComments": []
      }
    },
    {
      "eventInfo": {
        "context": {
          "siteTimezone": "Asia/Brunei",
          "entityPk": "8802089762861",
          "entityClass": "de.hybris.platform.core.model.order.OrderModel",
          "com.amway.core.events.model.AmwayEventQueueEntryModel": "8805597503930"
        },
        "isoCountryCode": "BN",
        "eventType": "LYNX_ORDER_UPDATE",
        "entityType": "salesorder",
        "sourceTimestamp": "2020-06-25T14:05:57.250+08:00",
        "sourceApplication": "HYBRIS",
        "affiliateCode": "100",
        "entityId": "7100029639",
        "sourceEventId": "8ab538d6-e525-4c8d-b1cf-411d562715f8",
        "accountId": "8055817",
        "sourceHost": "ip-10-127-165-86.ap-southeast-1.compute.internal"
      },
      "entity": {
        "lynxIsPCP": false,
        "paymentRequired": true,
        "bonusTransactionRequired": true,
        "addresses": [{
            "telephoneNumber": "03-7946 2800",
            "isoCountryCode": "BN",
            "line3": "Bandar Seri Begawan",
            "cityName": "Brunei",
            "line2": "Kampung Kiulap",
            "line1": "6 & 7, Block A, Kompleks Shakirin",
            "careOfName": "",
            "state": "BR",
            "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
            "postalCode": "BE1518",
            "id": "8804188225559"
          },
          {
            "telephoneNumber": "5494492",
            "isoCountryCode": "BN",
            "line3": "GADONG",
            "line4": "8171571",
            "cityName": "BDR SERI BEGAWAN",
            "line2": "KAMPONG RIMBA",
            "line1": "5 SIMPANG 12-32",
            "careOfName": "",
            "state": "BR",
            "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
            "postalCode": "BE3119",
            "id": "8802223521815"
          },
          {
            "telephoneNumber": "5494492",
            "isoCountryCode": "BN",
            "line3": "GADONG",
            "line4": "8171571",
            "cityName": "BDR SERI BEGAWAN",
            "line2": "KAMPONG RIMBA",
            "line1": "5 SIMPANG 12-32",
            "careOfName": "",
            "state": "BR",
            "emailAddress": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
            "postalCode": "BE3119",
            "id": "8802223521815"
          },
          {
            "telephoneNumber": "03-7946 2800",
            "isoCountryCode": "BN",
            "line3": "Bandar Seri Begawan",
            "cityName": "Brunei",
            "line2": "Kampung Kiulap",
            "line1": "6 & 7, Block A, Kompleks Shakirin",
            "careOfName": "",
            "state": "BR",
            "emailAddress": "myhelpdesk@Amway.com",
            "postalCode": "BE1518",
            "id": "8800157073431"
          }
        ],
        "totalOrderValue": 147.5,
        "lynxPaymentChangePaid": 0.0,
        "lynxIsRepair": false,
        "adjustments": [],
        "requestedDeliveryServiceLevel": "walkin",
        "lynxTenure": 0,
        "saleCountryCode": "BN",
        "orderDateTime": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.328+08:00",
        "invoiceSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "userAgent": "Suresh Mathiarasu",
        "orderStatus": "PICKUP_COMPLETE",
        "isoCurrencyCode": "BND",
        "fees": [{
          "feeCode": "walkin",
          "feeTaxTotalAmount": 0.0,
          "lynxRefunded": false,
          "feeAmount": 0.0,
          "feeTaxDetails": [{
            "taxAmount": 0.0,
            "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
          }]
        }],
        "bonusPeriod": "202006",
        "orderingPartyId": "40986385",
        "lynxPayerPartyId": "40986385",
        "salesChannelCode": "Point of Sale",
        "lynxIsEpp": false,
        "lynxPayerPartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
        "lynxDemandLocationName": "BN",
        "lynxDeliveryType": "pis",
        "paymentSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "orderPriceList": "AmwayDefaultABOPriceGroup",
        "lynxVolumePartyId": "40986385",
        "lynxHasSopEntries": false,
        "orderLines": [{
          "linePrice": 147.5,
          "itemType": "AmwayVariantProduct",
          "itemBV": 29.5,
          "lynxBmCode": [],
          "lynxInvoiceNumber": "130099000",
          "lynxLineAdjustedPV": 0.0,
          "shippedQuantity": 5,
          "lineStatus": "OPEN",
          "lynxProductSerialNumber": [],
          "lineUnitOfMeasure": "EA",
          "allocatedQuantity": 5,
          "linePVAmount": 95.0,
          "fulfillments": [{
            "fulfillmentLocation": "T45",
            "fulfilledItemRevision": "",
            "fulfilledSKU": "115383D",
            "uniqueFulfillmentID": "100000002118",
            "fulfilledBaseItemId": "115383D",
            "fulfilledDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:57.167+08:00",
            "fulfilledItemLot": "",
            "fulfilledQuantity": 5
          }],
          "actualShipDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:57.167+08:00",
          "lastUpdateDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.985+08:00",
          "lynxBillingAddressReference": "8802223521815",
          "cancelledQuantity": 0,
          "lynxBaseItemId": "115383D",
          "demandLocation": "T45",
          "backorderedQuantity": 0,
          "taxNotRequired": false,
          "lynxLineFulfillmentStatus": "SHIPPED",
          "lynxBirTaxPerUnit": 0.0,
          "pickupAddressReference": "8804188225559",
          "unallocatedQuantity": 0,
          "pendingQuantity": 0,
          "itemABOPrice": 29.5,
          "lineTaxTotalAmount": 0.0,
          "lynxIsSopLine": false,
          "lynxWasBackorder": false,
          "itemSuggestedRetailPrice": 37.0,
          "lineTotalValue": 147.5,
          "baseItemId": "115383D",
          "lynxMasterCode": [],
          "itemDescription": "ARTISTRY SIGNATURE COLOR Lipstick - Daring Red (06) (3.8g)",
          "lineTaxDetails": [{
            "taxAmount": 0.0,
            "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
          }],
          "shipAddressReference": "8804188225559",
          "lynxPickupAddressName": "BN",
          "lynxIsSopEntry": false,
          "lynxBirAcknowledgementResetCounter": "1",
          "lynxLineAdjustedBV": 0.0,
          "orderedQuantity": 5,
          "itemListPrice": 29.5,
          "fulfillmentType": "walkin",
          "returnedQuantity": 0,
          "actualDeliveryDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:57.167+08:00",
          "orderLineId": 0,
          "itemPV": 19.0,
          "lineBVAmount": 147.5
        }],
        "lynxFulfillmentAddressReference": "8800157073431",
        "cashierBatchId": "amwaybrunei-AM-BN-BN-T45-MY020394-1593058911313",
        "lynxOrderingPartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
        "totalBVAmount": 147.5,
        "lynxVolumeTransactions": [{
          "lynxInterfaceType": "ORDERS",
          "lynxInterfaceAttribute": "positive",
          "lynxPointValue": 95.0,
          "lynxTransactionTime": "2020-06-25T14:05:56.981+08:00",
          "lynxStatus": "CREATED",
          "lynxTransactionType": "ORDER",
          "lynxBonusPeriod": "202006",
          "lynxBusinessValue": 147.5
        }],
        "volumeSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "taxDetails": [{
          "taxAmount": 0.0,
          "taxCode": "BN_NO_SCOPE_VAT_SALES"
        }],
        "lynxUserType": "AmwayBusinessNature_1",
        "lynxPaymentTenderedAmount": 147.5,
        "lynxVolumePartyName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP",
        "lynxOrderCreatedBy": "MY020394",
        "lynxOms": "Hybris",
        "orderForSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "lynxPaymentInstalmentType": "PIF",
        "lynxMemberPoints": 0.0,
        "lynxContactPhone": "5494492",
        "totalPVAmount": 95.0,
        "inventoryTransactionRequired": true,
        "lynxIsEventBooking": false,
        "lynxBirCashierId": "MY020394",
        "refunds": [],
        "invoiceWithConsignmentRequired": false,
        "orderPeriod": "202006",
        "orderingSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "lynxContactEmailId": "vhwzezgj@rzrcy.bmh",
        "amwaySalesEntity": "780",
        "paymentStatus": "PAID",
        "storefront": "amwaybrunei",
        "lynxPaymentType": "PIF",
        "salesOrderId": "7100029639",
        "lynxOrderCategory": "selfOrder",
        "payments": [{
          "verificationDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:54.453+08:00",
          "lynxIsConnectedFlow": false,
          "paymentLocation": "T45",
          "lynxPaymentProcessedBy": "8055817",
          "paymentStatus": "ACCEPTED",
          "terminalId": "MY020394",
          "paymentReferenceId": "TXN-1593065154321",
          "payerSalesAccount": {
            "accountId": "8055817",
            "lynxPinLevel": "330",
            "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
            "affiliateCode": "100"
          },
          "paymentDate": "2020-06-25T14:05:54.456+08:00",
          "isoCurrencyCode": "BND",
          "lynxPaymentInformation": "",
          "paymentId": "831122002_4e7c1945-b49d-4c86-a0b8-a05b0cb805fa",
          "paymentValue": 147.5,
          "paymentMethod": "cash",
          "merchantId": "amway"
        }],
        "shipToSalesAccount": {
          "lynxBusinessStyle": "ROHANA LATIP & WAN ROSLAN",
          "accountId": "8055817",
          "lynxPinLevel": "330",
          "lynxName": "ROHANA BINTI HJ LATIP & WAN ROSLAN B WAN SU",
          "affiliateCode": "100"
        },
        "totalABORetailProfit": 0.0,
        "totalTaxAmount": 0.0,
        "lynxOrderType": "NORMAL_ORDER",
        "lynxComments": []
      }
    },
   

]



/* Get Result */
function getResult() {
  /* Read value from input fields */
  // var skills = $("#skills").val() || '',
  //   email = $("#email").val() || '',
    order = $("#order").val() || '';
      accountId = $("#accountId").val() || '';
    

  var result = [],
    i;

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if ((data[i]["order"].toUpperCase() === order.toUpperCase()) || (
        data[i]["accountId"].toUpperCase() === accountId.toUpperCase()) ) {
      result.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

$('#submit').click(function onClick() {
  var output = getResult();
  var html = '';
  $.each(output,function(key,value){
      html +='<tr>';
      html +='<td>'+ value.order + '</td>';
           html +='<td>'+ value.accountId + '</td>';
           html +='<td>'+ value.eventType + '</td>';
           html +='<td>'+ value.orderDateTime + '</td>';
                  html +='<td>'+ value.orderStatus + '</td>';
      
        html +='<td>'+ value.totalPVAmount + '</td>';
        html +='<td>'+ value.totalBVAmount + '</td>';
         html +='<td>'+ value.totalOrderValue + '</td>';
      html +='</tr>';
  });
$('table tbody').html(html);
});
```

But when ran the code i am getting the error message like :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined
    at getResult (script.js:1470)
    at HTMLInputElement.onClick (script.js:1479)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Can someone help me to resolve this? when i have asked my friend to try, its working in her system. I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: Show us a sample of `data` that causes the error as per [mcve]

Comment: Can you please check now?

Comment: You have `data[i]["order"]` in your if statement but your data doesn't have any object properties named `order`

Comment: you should check the values with console.log() before running the for loop it might shed some light on the issue if the value is undefined.

Comment: Also I just noticed that you don't declare order you just say order  = ...
you should use let order = ... and same goes for accountID

Answer (score 0):

Maybe be there is some undefined value for account or order in the data.

```
var b;
b.toUpperCase()
```

You will see the same error like yours.

```
const selectedOrder = order && order.toUpperCase();
const currentOrder = data[i]["order"] && data[i]["order"].toUpperCase();

const selectedAccoundId = accoundId && accoundId.toUpperCase();
const currentAccoundId = data[i]["accountId"].toUpperCase()

if (selectedOrder === currentOrder || selectedOrder === currentAccoundId) {
      result.push(data[i]);
}
```

You can add this inside your for loop. This will resolve your problem...

Theoretically, order and account id should be always there. So, I would like to request you to check if there is something missing in the data too.

Comment: i wrote code like this 
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const selectedOrder = order && order.toUpperCase();
    const currentOrder = data[i]["order"] && data[i]["order"].toUpperCase();

    const selectedAccoundId = accoundId && accoundId.toUpperCase();
    const currentAccoundId = data[i]["accountId"].toUpperCase()

      if (selectedOrder === currentOrder || selectedOrder === currentAccoundId) {
        result.push(data[i]);

    }
  }
  return result;
};

Comment: but i got error script.js:1473 Uncaught ReferenceError: accoundId is not defined
    at getResult (script.js:1473)
    at HTMLInputElement.onClick (script.js:1485)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)